# body data not sent in axios request

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I am trying to send data through axios request to my backend script, but the body looks empty.

Here's a request sent from front-end:

```
axios.request({
  method: 'GET',
  url: `http://localhost:4444/next/api`,
  headers: {
    'Authorization': token
  },
  data: {
    next_swastik: 'lets add something here'
  },

}).then((res)=>{  
  console.log("api call sucessfull",res);

}).catch((err)=>{
  console.log("api call unsucessfull",err);

  this.props.toggleLoading(false);
})
```

Here's a back-end:

```
app.get('/next/api', verifyToken, function(req, res) {
console.log(req.body);
```

})

But I am getting `{}` empty body. I am getting headers and other data but not data.

Comment: If you are sure that you are making the request by POST, maybe your problem is bodyParser. Please ensure that your express instance is using it.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

GET requests should not have a body.

Change the method from 'GET' to 'POST'

Like so:

```
axios.request({
  method: 'POST',
  url: `http://localhost:4444/next/api`,
  headers: {
    'Authorization': token
  },
  data: {
    next_swastik: 'lets add something here'
  },

})
```

and change your api to expect a post

```
app.post('/next/api', verifyToken, function(req, res) {
console.log(req.body);
});
```

**or**

Change the `data` property to `params`

```
axios.request({
  method: 'GET',
  url: `http://localhost:4444/next/api`,
  headers: {
    'Authorization': token
  },
  params: {
    next_swastik: 'lets add something here'
  },

})
```

and change the api to log out the params

```
app.get('/next/api', verifyToken, function(req, res) {
console.log(req.params);
});
```

and like @MaieonBrix said, make sure that your headers contain the content type that you are sending.

Comment: GET Bodies are no longer banished from HTTP requests, and suggesting to change it to a POST does not help those of us using an external API that we have no control over.

Comment: My answer was not for people hitting an external api that they don't control, it was for the question you see above. Also I said you "should not" have a GET not that you "could not"

Comment: Perhaps, but that is more down to opinion now. Since the standards now don't explicitly exclude GET bodies any more I'd say that 'should not' is a very personal opinion. This answer also comes up in Google when you search for answers about HTTP GET bodies so it is rather unhelpful in that sense.

Comment: @user37309 while they may no longer be _"banished"_, they are not supported in browsers at all.

Answer (score 10):

It looks like you only have two points left to make it work :

- one : the http method should be set to `POST` instead of `GET` since you want to send something.
- two : you can then add the http header (like what you did with the authorization header) `Content-Type`: 'application/json`

On the back-end don't forget to use some kind of body parser utility package like this one : [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser) and set it up with your app.

I suppose your server is using express, here is how you will do it with express :

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser')
const jsonParser = bodyParser.json();

app.use(jsonParser); // use it globally
app.get('your_route', jsonParser, otherMiddleware, (req, res) => ...); // use it for specific routes

/* ... rest of your code */
```

Answer (score 1):

If you get an error that "bodyParser is deprecated", try this -

```js
app.use(express.json()); //To parse JSON bodies (Applicable for Express 4.16+)
```

And use "post" method, if you want to get data from body of the HTTP request.

Comment: It's simple and working!! I didn't receive "bodyparser deprecated" error. but this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Because get requests... dont generally have bodies.  They are esentially what you type into a url bar. So instead of a body, you would want to use parameters.  If you wished to use them individually you use querystrings.

`url/posts?post=post123&comment=comment321`

in the below the request made to url/posts/post123/comment321 => will fill the two below parameters.

you must use post but comment is not required.

```
router.get("/posts/:post/:comment",async(req,res){
    const postPermlink = req.params.post
    const commentPermlink = req.params.comment ?? null
    const postDbEntry = await Posts.findOne({permLink: postPermlink})
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
this.axios('realties', { params: this.filter })
```