# Request body is not being passed from axios get call to Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, axios, postman

I have an issue while sending get request with a body in axios. It does not pass the body of the request to the backend.

Axios code looks like below

```
const FunctionName = (environment, page_num) => {

    axios.get(API_URL, 
            { params: 
              {
                 environment,
                 page_num
              },

            }).then(res => {
                console.log(res);
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log(err.response.data);
            });
}
```

I'm using Django as my backend and I'm receiving empty body i.e {} which causes bad request sent to the backend. I went through several stack overflow questions but none of them helped me. Can anyone please help me with this.

**Update**

My django code looks like below

```
class TestView(APIView);
    def get(self, request):
       environment = request.data['environment']
       page_num = request.data['page_num'] 
       ...
       ...
```

Here when I'm unable to get the environment or page_num data. The same request when I send from postman with the get call and content in the request of the body, it accepts and sends the response back.

**Re-Update**

I noticed that we have to use request.query_params['some_val'] incase we're passing the body in a request from Axios but request.query_params['some_val'] will not work if we send a request with the body in postman. I'm not sure it is normal behavior or not!

Comment: Try axios.post, axios.get request might have some limitations

Comment: @Ajay In my django APIView class there is another post method for creating data so that might conflict if I go with the post method.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [body data not sent in axios request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52561124/body-data-not-sent-in-axios-request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone who's facing the issue can find the answer below to the link.

Possible duplicate
[How to access get request data in django rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58207014/how-to-access-get-request-data-in-django-rest-framework)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but try this:

```
axios({
  method: "get",
  url: API_URL,
  body: {
    environment,
    page_num
  }
}).then(res => console.log(res.data));
```

In Django, are you try get body with `request.body`

Comment: No still the same issue.

Comment: when you specify data in the body of the request we have to specify with params object. As it mentioned in Axios docs https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: Are you try get body Django with `request.body` ?

Comment: I'm using request.data['page_num'] in django.

Comment: Since I'm using Django Rest Framework, to get the body of the request we need to use request.data.
https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/

Comment: I see the document [Requests and Responses](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/2-requests-and-responses/) with `request.data` just works for 'POST', 'PUT' and 'PATCH' methods. Are you try `request.GET['page_num']`

Comment: Yes, it works if I just send the data through postman with the body.