# How to access get request data in django rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, request, axios

How to access GET request data in django rest framework. In the docs, they have mentioned "For clarity inside your code, we recommend using request.query_params instead of the Django's standard request.GET"

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/

But when I use request.query_params.get('some_vaue') it gives me none even though I pass the data in the request body.

sample code example:

```
class TestView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        test = request.query_params.get('test')
        print('data',test)
        ...
        ...
        ...
```

When I pass some value in the body of the request in postman and print the value, it actually prints None.

**Update**

Below is my axios code

```
 axios.get(API_URL, {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            params: {
                page_num: 1, 
                test: 'test data'
            }
        })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err.response.data);
        });
```

**Re-Update:**

For testing purpose I printed out the request object like

```
print(request.__dict__)
```

so it printed out

```
{'_request': <WSGIRequest: GET '/api/my api url/?page_num=1&test=test+data'>, 'parsers': [<rest_framework.parsers.JSONParser object at 0x0000016742098128>, <rest_framework.parsers.FormParser object at 0x00000167420980B8>, <rest_framework.parsers.MultiPartParser object at 0x00000167420980F0>], 'authenticators': (), 'negotiator': <rest_framework.negotiation.DefaultContentNegotiation object at 0x0000016742098080>, 'parser_context': {'view': <app_name.views.APIClassName object at 0x0000016742280400>, 'args': (), 'kwargs': {}, 'request': <rest_framework.request.Request object at 0x0000016742107080>, 'encoding': 'utf-8'}, '_data': {}, '_files': <MultiValueDict: {}>, '_full_data': {}, '_content_type': <class 'rest_framework.request.Empty'>, '_stream': None, 'accepted_renderer': <rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer object at 0x00000167421070B8>, 'accepted_media_type': 'application/json', 'version': None, 'versioning_scheme': None, '_authenticator': None, '_user': <django.contrib.auth.models.AnonymousUser object at 0x0000016741FFAC88>, '_auth': None}
```

I could see that it is passing the data but not sure why if i do request.data['page_num'] or any other value it doesn't get the data.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you are using class based views :

> POST provides data in request.data and GET in request.query_params

If you are using function based views:

> request.data will do the work for both methods.

axios does not support sending params as body with get method , it will append params in url. so if you are using axios you will have to use query_params

Axios example code:

```
axios.get(API_URL, {
            params: {
                testData: 'test data',
                pageNum: 1
            }
        })
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err.response.data);
        });
```

DRF example code:

```
Class TestView(APIView):
    def get(self, request):
        test_data_var = request.query_params['testData']
        page_num_var = request.query_params['pageNum']
```

**Note:** 
If you're testing it in postman then put the get request query params in Params tab.

Comment: Yes that works fine in postman if I use request.data['test']. But when I use axios to send a get request with some data in the body, it actually gives KeyError exception. when printed out the request.data it was actually a blank object. But when i tried request.GET.get('test') I was able to get the data.

Comment: backend api is never depends on  which api plugin you are using for fronted @AashayAmballi

Comment: in axios you will have to mention  the method as well @AashayAmballi .

Comment: Yes, the same thing doesn't work if I pass the data from Axios.

Comment: I have mentioned the method. I'll update the axios code in my question

Comment: better use decorator or something @api_view(['GET]) before your view method .  request.Get.get is not good practice.

Comment: If I'm using APIView class then no need to use @api_view(['GET])  right?

Comment: and you also dont need to use `request.Get.get('test')`.  https://www.django-rest-framework.org/tutorial/3-class-based-views/    .  see post method here getting data using request.data

Comment: yes for post method it works perfectly fine but when I do the same thing for get request from axios, it gives me KeyError exception. As i said in the question when i printed out the request.data it was actually a blank object.

Comment: In the doc https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#query_params why they have mentioned "request.query_params is a more correctly named synonym for request.GET"?

Comment: KeyErrorException will occur when you are accessing a key from variable which is not dictionary .

Comment: @AashayAmballi . okay i told you before request.Get.get() is not best practice because if u change the method type this statement will not work. and thats why drf recommends that  use query_params so it will have no dependency on method

Comment: @check the  print(type(request.data))

Comment: Yes you're correct. I'm not sure why request.data['of something'] works in postman and not in axios. is there anything i've to set in axios call?

Comment: the type of request.data is dict in both axios and postman call.

Comment: @AashayAmballi try this .
`axios({
  method: 'get',
  url: '/user/12345',
  data: {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone'
  }
}); `

Comment: You're telling me to use post method instead of get?

Comment: I've tried this and when i try to access it in DRF it gives me None value. In axios docs they have mentioned to use params: { firstName: 'Fred' } instead of data: { firstName: 'Fred'}

Comment: @AashayAmballi  no they mentioned both in axios . https://github.com/axios/axios

Comment: I don't see using data: { key: value } for get method. I can only see params: { key: value}. Also saw this question regarding axios where they have  mentioned to use params.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52561124/body-data-not-sent-in-axios-request

Comment: @AashayAmballi if you scroll down search Axios Api  title

Comment: Yes, it is for post request not for get. They have clearly mentioned the method 'post'

Comment: @AashayAmballi you can use any method that was just an example for post. i also work in axios only

Comment: Yeah, but if I use get method and use data: {key: value} it does not pass any data to DRF. when i try to access it it will be a blank object.

Comment: @AashayAmballi  ok that answer i posted was for accessing the params using drf as you asked.

Comment: @AashayAmballi i would suggest you open one more question   for specific behavior of postman and axios  and respective codes and error .    because if with postman my answer is working then cause is with your axios code i must say.

Comment: @AashayAmballi Upvote and accept this as answer because it is working with postman . and open another question for i mentioned above

Comment: I'm not sure which category's error it is. Is it the error from postman or axios or DRF. I am unclear about this.

Comment: @AashayAmballi if u need more assistance open google meet and invite me there . njain1768@gmail.com

Comment: @AashayAmballi if with postman it is working then Drf is having no problem .. simple

Comment: No for postman I was using request.data['some_data'] only. On this topic actually yesterday I had asked this question and I answered (edited now). But I don't think it is a proper solution. Please have a look
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58184676/request-body-is-not-being-passed-from-axios-get-call-to-django-rest-framework

Comment: I've sent this post a few minutes before when you were telling that data: {key:value} can be passed with any request method.

Comment: @AashayAmballi one more thing i will suggest that if method is get you should send the data in url .  otherwise change the method as Post.    Thats why get and post are been developed

Comment: @AashayAmballi I have updated my answer . check that para . and update me

Comment: I've added content-type: 'application'/json' as request header but still no help. I have updated axios code in my question.

Comment: @AashayAmballi  you are not sending correct data. i ahve updated my answer check this

Comment: @AashayAmballi  ,param were not in json format you sending

Comment: still no help, even if I enclose with quotes it doesn't work.

Comment: @AashayAmballi ok. this is strange .  by the way use post method as you are sending data  in body. (for now.)

Comment: @AashayAmballi   if for post man request.query_param is working or not??

Comment: For postman request.query_param doesn't work, it only works with request.data.

Comment: I have updated my one observation in the question please have a look.

Comment: @AashayAmballi  you are using post method in postman . check again . you are getting confused

Comment: No bro i'm using get method only. I can share you the screenshot if possible

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200326/discussion-on-answer-by-naveen-jain-how-to-access-get-request-data-in-django-res).

Answer (score 0):

For me the accepted answer did not work.

A much simplier solution I saw no one mention is the following :

**Append them to the URL like this  :  *`yourApi.com/subdomain/?parameter1=something`***

- `Axios.js`

```
const target = "someApiYouWantToFetch.com"
let parameter = "DataYouWantToSend"
axios.get(`${target}?parameter=${parameter }`)
```

- `views.py`

```
def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs): #or def list()
    data = request.GET.get('name')
```

Comment: It's not best practice to use Django's request.GET.get in Django Rest Framework. As it's mentioned in the official documentation.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#query_params

and In Axios, as your params grow the harder it will be to read the URL if you just keep appending those to your URL. So it's better to pass those parmas values as an object.

Answer (score 0):

In DRF if you want to access ***request.GET*** you should use `request.request.GET`

for example

```
@action(methods=['GET',], detail=False)
def activation(request, *args, **kwargs):
    uid = request.request.GET.get('uid')
    token = request.request.GET.get('token')
```

Comment: It's not best practice to use Django's request.GET.get in Django Rest Framework. As it's mentioned in the official documentation. https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#query_params.

Comment: I know but some times request.data doesn't  work so you need to use this