# How do I use the response from ModelSet view inside my view in Django?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a class defined as :

```
class ObjectView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = serializers.ObjectSerialzer
    queryset = ObjectModel.objects.all()
```

The serializer is defined as:

```
class ObjectSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
   
    class Meta:
        model = CustomUser
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'username')
```

This creates all the necessary endpoints with various methods like `get`, `post`, `put` etc.. I want to use the data returned from this View with the method `get` inside of a view. Is there a way to do it or a better way to achieve this function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to access get request data in django rest framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58207014/how-to-access-get-request-data-in-django-rest-framework)

Comment: The data returned by a GET is just a serialised representation of `ObjectModel.objects.all()`, can't you just re-use this queryset in your other view?

Comment: @IainShelvington Do I use it  as `data = ObjectView.queryset`? I am new to DRF so not very used to it.

Comment: What do you mean by using the data inside a view? `data = ObjectModel.objects.all()` would get you the same queryset

Comment: Hi @qg2byte! I think there is a lack of clarity regarding what your actual aim is. Could you clarify what exactly you want to achieve by giving an example?

Comment: I want to use the response returned by the `get` method from the ObjectView class in a separate view, let's say `view_getdetails`., which is a function-based view