# res.send() not sending back complete data set

Tags: javascript, express, axios

hoping you all can help me solve this mystery.  I’ve created an endpoint for my API:

```js
apiRouter.get("/username", async (req, res) => {
  const { username } = req.body;
  try {
    const user = await getUserByUsername(username);

    res.send({ message: "This is your user", user });
    console.log("this is user", user);
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
});
```

It’s a GET route that should send back the a message and a user object in this fashion when the user interacts with this url path:

```js
 http://localhost:3000/api/users/username
```

When I access the endpoint via, Postman, I get back both the message and the user object. Something that looks like this:

```js
{
    "message": "This is your user",
    "user": {
        "customer_id": 5,
        "first_name": "Jessica",
        "last_name": "Blue",
        "email": "baker@space.com",
        "username": "jess1",
        "password": "1234",
        "address_1": "123 pretty lane",
        "address_2": "Apt 31",
        "city": "Riverside",
        "state": "California"
    }
}
```

However, when I access the route, via my frontend, the **message** comes back but not the **user**.  I’m using the following method to make the call to the server:

```js
export async function getUserByUsername(username) {
  try {
    const { data } = await axios.get("/api/users/username", {
      username,
    });
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  } catch (error) {
    throw error;
  }
}
```

I'm really not sure why the user isn’t being sent back with the response.  The route works, I’m just not getting back my expected response.  I’ve spent a couple hours trying to find a fix with no luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YCmhH.jpg)

Comment: Try `res.send( { message: "This is your user", user: { ...user } } );`

Comment: Both postman and chrome devtool can transform your request into curl command. You can compare to see what exactly is different.

Comment: change `req.body` to `req.query`

Comment: Are you sending a body with a GET? I'm pretty sure your axios request has to be a POST.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [body data not sent in axios request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52561124/body-data-not-sent-in-axios-request)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently you can't send a body with get requests in most browsers. so you've two options:

change your backend method to POST:

```
apiRouter.post("/username", async (req, res) => {
  const { username } = req.body;
  .
  .
  .
}
```

and use axios like this:

```
const { data } = await axios.post("/api/users/username", {
  username,
});
```

or if you want to stick with the get method accept the username as a query or  a param:

```
apiRouter.get("/username/:username", async (req, res) => {
  const { username } = req.params;
  .
  .
  .
}
```

and use axios like this:

```
const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/users/username/${username}`);
```

or

```
apiRouter.get("/username", async (req, res) => {
  const { username } = req.query;
  .
  .
  .
}
```

and use axios like this:

```
const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/users/username`, { params: { username } });
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using a `GET` request with `body`. Although it's possible, but [not advisable](https://stackoverflow.com/a/983458/5049799), to do so when you create your own request through `Postman`, `axios` probably ignores the `body` param when using a `GET` request and doesn't include it in the request.

So my suggestion would be to place the `username` param in the request params (`req.params`) or request query (`req.query`) and try to get it from there.

You can find more details about `req.params`: [here](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html), and about `req.query`: [here](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.query).

Comment: it wouldn't be in `req.params`

Answer (score 0):

I think it's might be because of the async await approach you're using in the endPoint it self, can you try running this line in your terminal:
`npm install express-async-errors --save`
after that go to index.js (your backend route file) and add this line over here:
`import 'express-async-errors';`
and try again, Hopefully, this will solve your issue