# Axios not sending body

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, axios, get

Axios not sending body to my API.

```
router.get('/login', async function(req,res) {
  try {
    const email  = req.body.email;
    const pass  = req.body.pass;
    const users = await pool.query("select username from users where username=$1 and password=$2", [email, pass]);
    if(users.rows[0])
      res.json(users.rows[0]['username']!=null);
    else
      res.json(users)
      console.log(req.body)
    console.log(email,pass)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err.message);
  }
});
```

When I console.log the req.body it after running GetData

```
async function GetData() {

    const email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    const pass = document.getElementById("pass").value;
    const response = await axios.get("http://localhost:3002/login",
    {
      body: JSON.stringify({"email":  email, "pass" : pass})
    })
    console.log(response.config.body);
    console.log(response.data.rows)
  }
```

The body is said to be {} an empty object.

How do I send the body through axios the same way insomnia is sending a body.

When using insomnia and the exact same body it returns true as it should.
[image]

Comment: try using `post` instead of `get`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [body data not sent in axios request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52561124/body-data-not-sent-in-axios-request)

Answer (score 0):

GET doesn’t accept sending a body, use POST instead:

```
router.post('/login', async function(req,res) {

// …

const response = await axios.post("http://localhost:3002/login", { email, pass })
```

Also, the response.config.body is not a thing, if you look at request config documentation, there is the property “data”, rather than “body”.

```
console.log(response.config.data);
```

Hopefully that helps!